Postgres dump import appears successful but imports no data
I’m running Postgres in a Docker container (PostGIS, specifically). If I create a database dump from a production database then import it into the container, the output I receive looks successful, but no tables are created. I have noticed a schema is created, but this is all I can see. However, if I retry the import it complains that the indexes etc. already exist, so it’s doing something but I can’t figure out what.
Possibly worth noting I’ve temporarily removed the volume from the container to remove the possibility of volume permission issues.
Creating the dump with:
pg_dump postgres://CONNECTIONSTRING > dump.sql

Then in psql I’m running
CREATE DATABASE db_name;
\i dump.sql

And I receive
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
 set_config 
------------
 
(1 row)

SET
SET
SET
SET
CREATE SCHEMA
ALTER SCHEMA
CREATE EXTENSION
COMMENT
SET
SET
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
…truncated

But \dt says “Did not find any relations”
If I then import again:
psql:dump.sql:64: ERROR:  relation "accounts" already exists
ALTER TABLE
…truncated

A schema is being created however, I can see it with \dn. This is about at the limit of my knowledge however, I don’t really know what this means, and definitely don’t know where the data is going!

The issue was the dump created a schema which all the tables lived inside. In order to see it, I needed to set the search path to look in that schema with:
SET search_path TO tracker_production;

